# Change text immediately following a checkbox input

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="email" /> Email
```

Elsewhere in my code, I need to change this checkbox to check and also change the description, like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="email" checked /> Email (enabled)
```

I've tried:

```
  $('input[name=email]').val('test');
```

But that doesn't change the text. How do I mark it checked and also change the text?

Comment: you can't change a text that not inside an element, my suggestion is to get your description contained in a `<span>` element and give it an id and for checking the `checkbox` you have to use `$('input[name=email]').prop('checked',true);`

Comment: Use a `label` with the `input` and change the `label` text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="email" /> Email
```

to:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="email" /> <span>Email</span>
```

and your code is:

```
$('input[name=email]').prop('checked',true).next('span').html('Email (enabled)');
```

Comment: I suggest adding `aria-label='Email'`, since otherwise blind people using screen readers will have a harder time understanding the purpose of the input when navigating the form: `<input type="checkbox" name="email" aria-label='Email' /> <span>Email</span>`

Answer (score 1):

I think for your scenario using a `label` element would be more appropriate, so something like:

```
<label name="email" for="email">Email</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="email" id="email" checked />
```

This will add the option to click on the label and have the checkbox toggle.
Here is the jquery to make it change text:

```
$("label[name=email]").text("Email (enabled)");
```

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/DVEuq/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses **CSS only**:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='email' aria-label='Email'><span>Email</span>

input[name='email']:checked + span::after {
  content: ' (enabled)'
}
```

Add a '' around the 'Email', and target it with css3 with the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) and adding [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aafter) content when the [:checked pseudoselector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3achecked) is active on the input with `name='email'`.

Note that there is an `aria-label` attribute on the input. This instructs assistive technologies for the blind identify the inputs meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `label` element for the text label of a checkbox, and the `.prop` jQuery method to toggle the checked state.

```
<input type='checkbox' id='emailcheckbox' name='email' />
<label for='emailcheckbox'></label>

<script>
$('#emailcheckbox').prop('checked', true);
$('label[for=emailcheckbox]').text('Email');
</script>
```